Make Table inside B-Col the size of the column. (Vue-Bootstrap)
I have this in my Vue component
<b-modal ...>
  <b-row>
    <b-col sm="12">
      <table >
        <tr v-for=... :key="key">
          <td><strong>{{ key }}: </strong></td>
          <td>
            {{ item }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
....

If an item is very long, then the table is larger than the b-col
How to force a table to be the same size as a b-col.
I would like not to only hide with
overflow: hidden;

Because the table is still too large, just hidden.

Without your css it's hard to know, but one way you could do this is to set your table to use table-layout: fixed.
You can also get fancy and overflow the text in each cell. Something like the following will make your table cells look nice:
td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

